# Magento add attribute on top of the group

Tags: magento

I have magento 1.8. and i want to add product attribute in product. I can do all of that but when I want to add specific attribute to be located on top of others (sorting order in back office) in group. How can i do this?

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'my_subtitle', array(
'attribute_model'                 => NULL,
'backend'                         => NULL,
'type'                            => 'text',
'table'                           => NULL,
'frontend'                        => NULL,
'input'                           => 'text',
'label'                           => 'Subtitle',
'frontend_class'                  => NULL,
'source'                          => NULL,
'required'                        => '0',
'user_defined'                    => true,
'default'                         => NULL,
'unique'                          => '0',
'note'                            => NULL,
'input_renderer'                  => NULL,
'visible'                         => '1',
'searchable'                      => '1',
'filterable'                      => '1',
'comparable'                      => '1',
'visible_on_front'                => '1',
'is_html_allowed_on_front'        => '1',
'is_used_for_price_rules'         => '0',
'filterable_in_search'            => '0',
'used_in_product_listing'         => '1',
'used_for_sort_by'                => '0',
'is_configurable'                 => '0',
'visible_in_advanced_search'      => '0',
'position'                        => '0',
'wysiwyg_enabled'                 => '0',
'used_for_promo_rules'            => '0',
'apply_to'                        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
'global'                          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
'sort_order'                 => -1,  // Or 0
```

Ie.

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'my_subtitle', array(
    'sort_order'                 => -1,  // Or 0
    ...
    )
);
```

This way, your new attribute should be displayed before the rest, as per the `sort_order`.

Comment: I think it does, from what I understand, the request is to add a new custom attribute positioned on top of the rest, and than can be achieved by the `sort_order`. For what it's worth, edited the answer to make it somewhat clearer.